# 2NN classifier with neighbours having different labels

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

In 2-Nearest-Neighbourhood classifier, given a input x, and 2 neighbours of x have different
labels, what can I assign as label for x? (Assuming I am not weighting neighbours based on distance)?

Comment: You can always just label this with more common classs...
That's the problem that basically explains why kNN with even number of neighbors isn't used without weighing.